# Itext 7 Cuando agrego una imagen el pdf de resultado no la tiene

Tags: c#, itextsharp, itext

tengo un metodo en c# que realiza este procedimiento pero no me inserta la imagen

el codigo esta de la siguiente manera

private void itextpdf(string prefijo, decimal numerofactura, string pdfplantilla, string rutapdf)

```
    {
        try
        {
            string destino = rutapdf;
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new FileStream(destino, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfplantilla), writer);
            Document document = new Document(pdf);

            // Creating an ImageData object 
            string rutaimageqr = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\qr.png";
            bool fileExist = File.Exists(rutaimageqr);
            if (fileExist)
            {
                // Creating an Image object 
                iText.Layout.Element.Image img = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(ImageDataFactory.Create(rutaimageqr));
                // position in document
                img.SetFixedPosition(25, 500);
                ////img.SetFixedPosition(25, 100);
                img.SetHeight(95);
                img.SetWidth(95);

                //*Agrega imagen a documento.
                document.Add(img);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Imagen no Existe!.");
            }

            pdf.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            throw;
        }

    }
```

entonces me crea el pdf de destino pero sin la imagen, no se si debe ser un formato en especifico de la imagen o el pdf que trato de modificar esta protegido
auqnue el pdf que estoy usando para insertar la imagen se crea con crystal report 8, no se si tiene algo que ver.
gracias de antemano.

realice el siguiente ajuste separando el paragraph del la imagen y solo imprime el paragraph la imagen no la muestra

Comment: realice el siguiente cambio separe el paragraph de la imagen y solo me agrego el paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Estas agregando la imagen a un `Paragraph` pero debes agregarla a el documento directamente:

```
 Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Image Example-");
 //paragraph.Add(img);
 document.Add(paragraph);
 //*Agrega imagen a documento.
 document.Add(img);
```

Te sugiero también verificar si la imagen de acuerdo a su ruta en realidad existe:

```
 try
        {
            string destino = rutapdf; 
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new FileStream(destino, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfplantilla), writer);
            Document document = new Document(pdf);

            // Creating an ImageData object 
            string rutaimageqr = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\qr.png";

            bool fileExist = File.Exists(rutaimageqr);
            if (fileExist)
            {
            // Creating an Image object 
            iText.Layout.Element.Image img = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(ImageDataFactory.Create(rutaimageqr));
            // position in document
            img.SetFixedPosition(25, 500);
            ////img.SetFixedPosition(25, 100);
            img.SetHeight(95);
            img.SetWidth(95);

            //*Agrega imagen a documento.
            document.Add(img);
            }else{
                Console.WriteLine("Imagen no Existe!.");
            }

            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Image Example-");
            paragraph.Add(img);
            document.Add(paragraph);

            pdf.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: ya lo intente solo me muestra el paragrph la imagen sigue sin mostrarla

Comment: si realizas una prueba no agregando el paragraph y agregando directamente laimagen al documento?, revisa si la imagen en el path especificado existe realmente.

Comment: agregue las linea de código para verificar si la imagen existe pero sigue sin mostrar la imagen en el pdf...

Comment: voy a probar solo la imagen sin el paragraph

Comment: despues de quitar el paragraph sigue sin mostrar la imagen

Comment: Existe la imagen?  bool fileExist = File.Exists(rutaimageqr); ?

Comment: si si existe depurando el código linea a linea si encuentra la imagen sin problemas